# How to animate/update just parts of activity?

Tags: android, animation, android-studio

I'm working on an android application, which get a number from the user and calculate 20/40/60 and 80% of it.

The app has an fixed header part. The other part needs to be updated after pressing the "calculate!"-button. The way I want to implement it is to do a flowing exchange from right to left.

The problem is, I don't want to update the whole activity, just the linear layout part where the editText field and the button is.

Is this possible or should I duplicate this activity and redesign it for the result and do a activity change?

I looked for animations/transitions, but all I found or clearly understand was the animation between activities.

I hope you understand what I tried to say, if not, ask for the unclear part.

I created for a better understanding a sketch of the apps view.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Fragments.

1 Activity with the header and a fragment container then 2 Fragments, one for enter number screen and one for calculation screen.

Comment: is it possible to change the animation between two fragments?

Comment: Yes it is, with `FragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations()`. See doc here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html